# Drupal Module to sync with external database

Tags: drupal-7

I have been trying to synchronize Drupal 7 user account with external DB. Can anyone suggest me best module to do so?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using the external data for? You would most likely be writing your own module if you're trying to get custom DB output. The best way to deal with data from an external DB is to set it up in your settings.php file. Once you've done so you can actively switch to query the second database in any of your modules. Check this out for information - http://drupal.org/node/18429